# How to configureStore Mutiple middleware in RTK query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

redux-toolkit given original doc--

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// Or from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { pokemonApi } from './services/pokemon'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    // Add the generated reducer as a specific top-level slice
    [pokemonApi.reducerPath]: pokemonApi.reducer,
  },
  // Adding the api middleware enables caching, invalidation, polling,
  // and other useful features of `rtk-query`.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(pokemonApi.middleware),
})

// optional, but required for refetchOnFocus/refetchOnReconnect behaviors
// see `setupListeners` docs - takes an optional callback as the 2nd arg for customization
setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

my code

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import newletterReducer from '../slicers/newletter/newsletterSlicer'
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { getmoviesdetails } from '../slicers/service/getmoviedetails'
import { authService } from '../slicers/service/auth/authService'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        newsletter: newletterReducer,
        [getmoviesdetails.reducerPath]: getmoviesdetails.reducer,
        [authService.reducerPath]: authService.reducer,
    },
    middleware:
        (getdefaultMiddleware) =>
            {return getdefaultMiddleware().concat(getmoviesdetails.middleware)
                ,getdefaultMiddleware().concat(authService.middleware)}
                     
            

})

setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

they given error
buildInitiate.ts:248 Warning: **Middleware** for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "getmoviedetails" has not been added to the store.
Features like automatic cache collection, automatic refetching etc. will not be available.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
middleware:
        (getdefaultMiddleware) =>
            getdefaultMiddleware()
            .concat([
                     getmoviesdetails.middleware, 
                     authService.middleware
                   ])
```

Basically you can pass all your middleware in a array.

Comment: This definitely seems cleaner than chaining .concat()

Comment: i like this style

Answer (score 6):

```js
getdefaultMiddleware().concat(getmoviesdetails.middleware).concat(authService.middleware)
```

But you really should only have one api unless those are completely independent apis that will never have any overlapping data ever.

Quoting from the docs:

> Typically, you should only have one API slice per base URL that your application needs to communicate with. For example, if your site fetches data from both /api/posts and /api/users, you would have a single API slice with /api/ as the base URL, and separate endpoint definitions for posts and users. This allows you to effectively take advantage of automated re-fetching by defining tag relationships across endpoints.

> For maintainability purposes, you may wish to split up endpoint definitions across multiple files, while still maintaining a single API slice which includes all of these endpoints. See code splitting for how you can use the injectEndpoints property to inject API endpoints from other files into a single API slice definition.

Comment: I'm sorry, but "this is not working" doesn't really help diagnose. What is not working exactly? What are symptoms? Also, the code is not really readable. Maybe either edit it into the question or open a new question if it's a new question?

Comment: Hi , this is link please answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447522/how-to-automated-re-fetching-data-in-rtk-query