# how to Automated Re-fetching data in RTK query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

when i move next page or move to another page or update data ...data is not refetch ...when I reload the page then refetch data ...without reload how to refetch data using RTK query..

this is code

```
export const userService = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'userService',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/' }),
    tagTypes: ["Userdetail",'Profile_update'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getuserdetails: builder.query({
            query: () => ({
                url: 'userdetails',
                // method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'auth-token': localStorage.getItem('loginToken')
                }
            }),
            providesTags : ['Userdetail']
        }),

        updateuserdetail: builder.mutation({
            query: (newbody) => {
                const {id,...data} = newbody
                return{
                    url: `profile_update/${id}`,
                    method: 'PUT',
                    body: data,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json',
                        'auth-token': localStorage.getItem('loginToken')
                    }
                }
            },
            invalidatesTags :['Profile_update']
        }),
    })

})
```

call useGetuserdetailsQuery each component when render anothing to work

```
function ProtectedRouter(props) {
    const responseinfo  = useGetuserdetailsQuery({},{ refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true })
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const { Component  } = props 
    const login = localStorage.getItem('loginToken')
    console.log(responseinfo)
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useeefect working')
        if (responseinfo.data) {            
            if (responseinfo.data.errormsg) {               
                if (responseinfo.data.errormsg.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
                    localStorage.removeItem('loginToken')
                    navigate('/login',{state:{'logoutmsg':responseinfo.data.errormsg}})
                    navigate(0)
                }
            }
        }
    })
    
    return (
        <>
         {login? <Component /> : <Navigate to='/login' />}
        
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try with `refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true` or. `refetchOnMountOrArgChange: <number in sec (After how much seconds it has to refetch)>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the page where you are fetching the data using `useGetuserdetailsQuery`, Use this `refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true`. It will re-fetch the data when the component mount or its arguments are updated.

```
useGetuserdetailsQuery({}, { refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true })
```

This documentation will be helpful for you
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi

Comment: sorry Its autocorrect but I said not working

Comment: Did you try with a number?

Answer (score 2):

Your `providesTags` in query

```
 providesTags : ['Userdetail']
```

and `invalidatesTags` in mutation do not match.

```
invalidatesTags :['Profile_update']
```

that is why rtk is not re-fetching automatically.

`providesTags` will add a tag to the query. in your case `useGetuserdetailsQuery` is tagged with "Userdetail". Now whenever you make a mutation, you have to tell this mutation, which query you want it to be re-fetched. You tell this with `invalidatesTags` property. If you had this

```
invalidatesTags :['Userdetail']
```

After `useUpdateUserDetail` mutation run, this mutation would find the query with 'Userdetail' tag name, it would run that query again so your state and server are in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `localStorage.getItem('loginToken')` inside your `query`, but pass it in as an argument. RTK Query will keep the cache value if the argument stays the same and it will do a new request if the argument changed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getPost: build.query({
      query: () => 'post',
      keepUnusedDataFor: 0,
    }),
  }),
})
```

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#keepunuseddatafor