# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'invalidatesTags')

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to register on a React app using Redux-Toolkit RTK
I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'invalidatesTags')
    at calculateProvidedByThunk (buildThunks.ts:629:1)
    at handler (invalidationByTags.ts:31:1)
    at index.ts:120:1
    at index.ts:102:1
    at index.ts:102:1
    at index.js:20:1
    at immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:253:1
    at dispatch (redux.js:691:1)
    at createAsyncThunk.ts:682:1
    at step (index.ts:4:1)
```

Code where I'm using the query:

```js
const Register = () => {
  const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState("");
  const [lastname, setLastname] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [cPassword, setCPassword] = useState("");

  // const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false);

  const [registerUser, { isLoading }] = useRegisterMutation();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (password !== cPassword) {
      // setIsLoading(false)
      toast.error(`Passwords don't match`);
      return;
    }
    const newUser = { firstname, lastname, email, password, role_id: 2 };
    try {
      const data = await registerUser(newUser).unwrap();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};
```

my authApi:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const authApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ROOT_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: "/users/login",
        method: "post",
        body,
      }),
      register: builder.mutation({
        query: (body) => ({
          url: "/users/register",
          method: "post",
          body,
        }),
      }),
      resetPassword: builder.mutation({
        query: (body) => ({
          url: "/resetPassword",
          method: "PATCH",
          body,
        }),
        setNewPassword: builder.mutation({
          query: (body, token) => ({
            url: `/resetPassword/${token}`,
            method: "PATCH",
            body,
          }),
        }),
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useLoginMutation,
  useRegisterMutation,
  useResetPasswordMutation,
  useSetNewPasswordMutation,
  authApi,
};
```

Another API (`adminApi` which has the same `reducerPath` (adminApi.js))

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const adminApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ROOT_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = getState().auth.JWT;
      if (token) {
        headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
        return headers;
      }
    },
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Categories", "Products", "Tva", "Product"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCategoriesAdmin: builder.query({
      query: () => "/categories/getAllAdmin",
      providesTags: ["Categories", "Products"],
    }),
    getProductsAdmin: builder.query({
      query: () => "/products/getAllAdmin",
      providesTags: ["Categories", "Products"],
    }),
    getOneProductAdmin: builder.query({
      query: (id) => `/products/getOneAdmin/${id}`,
    }),
    getTvaAdmin: builder.query({
      query: () => "/TVA/getAllAdmin",
      providesTags: ["Tva"],
    }),
    addProduct: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: "/products/createOne",
        method: "post",
        body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Categories", "Products"],
    }),
    updateProductPut: builder.mutation({
      query: (o) => ({
        url: `/products/updateOnePut/${o.id}`,
        method: "PUT",
        body: o.body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Categories", "Products"],
    }),
    updateProductPatch: builder.mutation({
      query: (o) => ({
        url: `/products/updateOnePatch/${o.id}`,
        method: "PATCH",
        body: o.body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Categories", "Products"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetCategoriesAdminQuery,
  useGetTvaAdminQuery,
  useGetProductsAdminQuery,
  useAddProductMutation,
  useUpdateProductPutMutation,
  useUpdateProductPatchMutation,
  useGetOneProductAdminQuery,
  adminApi,
};
```

and my store

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authReducer from "./slices/authSlice";
import adminReducer from "./slices/adminSlice";
import shopReducer from "./slices/shopSlice";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { shopApi } from "./api/shopApi";
import { authApi } from "./api/authApi";
import { adminApi } from "./api/adminApi";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  admin: adminReducer,
  shop: shopReducer,
  [authApi.reducerPath]: authApi.reducer,
  [shopApi.reducerPath]: shopApi.reducer,
  [adminApi.reducerPath]: adminApi.reducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    const allMiddleware = [
      authApi.middleware,
      shopApi.middleware,
      adminApi.middleware,
      thunk,
    ];
    serializableCheck: false;
    return getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }).concat(
      ...allMiddleware
    );
  },
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Every get queries are working well, as well as the post request from the `adminApi`.
The `registerMutation` is working, the user is created on the DB, but I'm wondering why I get this error.

Answer (score 3):

I also got this issue and I solved it by providing different names for `reducerPath`.

If we either provide same name to `reducerPath` or not providing `reducerPath` at all, this error will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by following their docs!

[This link will take you exactly where they (RTK docs) talk about it](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#reducerpath)

> The reducerPath is a unique key that your service will be mounted to in your store. If you call createApi more than once in your application, you will need to provide a unique value each time. Defaults to 'api'.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem and I found the answer. The error is caused by two apis that has same base url. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72434804/how-to-configurestore-mutiple-middleware-in-rtk-query#:%7E:text=But%20you%20really,relationships%20across%20endpoints.).

> Typically, you should only have one API slice per base URL that your application needs to communicate with. For example, if your site fetches data from both /api/posts and /api/users, you would have a single API slice with /api/ as the base URL, and separate endpoint definitions for posts and users. This allows you to effectively take advantage of automated re-fetching by defining tag relationships across endpoints.

And if you want to separate definitions, take a look at [this site.](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/code-splitting)

I hope this answer will solve your problem. I'm not English speaker, so please excuse my poor english. Thank you for reading.